# Is it possible to use ForEach which changes the array depending on userInput value

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I was wondering if it is possible when having this array

```
marginIDs = [3005, 3002, 3007, 3014, 3095, 3025, 3004]
```

and know that the marginBase = **3000** (marginID is created by the marginBase and the numberID)

to create an array that consists only the numbersID (or to override the marginIDs)

i.e. `[5, 2, 7, 14, 95, 25, 4]`
 with **ForEach**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create a new array then you can use the `.map` array function as the other answers have specified. If you actually want to mutate the array, then you have to reference it by index as you have no control over the array from within the forEach function:

```
var marginBase = 3000;
var marginIds = [3005, 3002, 3007, 3014, 3095, 3025, 3004];
marginIds.forEach(function (marginId, index) {
    marginIds[index] = marginId - marginBase;
});
```

Comment: Simply `marginIds[index] -= marginBase`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` for this:

```
var mapped = marginIDs.map(function(m) { return m - marginBase });
```

Not that this is not supported for some older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

With Array#forEach:

```js
var marginIDs = [3005, 3002, 3007, 3014, 3095, 3025, 3004],
    marginBase = 3000,
    base = [];

marginIDs.forEach(function (id) {
    base.push(id - marginBase);
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(base, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Solution for overwriting the original array

```js
var marginIDs = [3005, 3002, 3007, 3014, 3095, 3025, 3004],
    marginBase = 3000;

marginIDs.forEach(function (id, i , array) {
    array[i] = id - marginBase;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(marginIDs, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```